# How Create Tabbed Page Renderer for iOS to not show "MORE" button ? instead Scroll-able Tab?

Tags: forms, xamarin, tabbedpage

I want Scroll- able Tabbed page Renderer for iOS. like in Android tabbed pages they are default scroll-able.its ok if its in bottom